# Are NASA's chase planes ever flown by non-astronauts?

Tags: nasa

NASA maintains a fleet of [T-38](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_T-38_Talon#NASA) aircraft for [training](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/shuttle/flyout/t38flyout.html) and as a chase plane for spacecraft.  **When used for that latter role, were the T-38s ever flown by non-astronauts?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, chase pilot [Charles Justiz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Justiz) was a non-astronaut, though his biography certainly suggests he could have qualified; he applied for the astronaut class of 1985. According to [this CollectSpace thread](http://www.collectspace.com/ubb/Forum38/HTML/001262.html) he flew chase for STS-5 and STS-41D among other missions. The thread names several other chase pilots; I didn't run down all of them but at least one other, Richard Laidley, appears to have been another non-astronaut.

Comment: JSC's Aircraft Operations Division was a starting point in NASA for quite a few pilots who later became astronauts - Kevin Kregel, Greg C. Johnson just off the top of my head. Some systems engineers too - Nicole Stott and Steve Nagel.  Flying and/or working on the Shuttle Training Aircraft was a definite plus on your application, it seems.